Permanently modify default symbology in QGIS when adding a vector layer
I am working with a lot of vector layers in a lot of different QGIS projects on a daily basis. When I add a vector layer, I systematically change the stroke symbology to "No line" (transparent color would work too). I am looking for a way to set up QGis so that, whatever the project, all vector layer are always added without the stroke/line. That would be a change to the default configuration of QGis I suppose.
I am aware of the following topics, the solutions work for a single project, but this is an option that one needs to setup for every single project, and I wished it'd apply to all the projects that I open. I have looked at the "user profile" but I couldn't find anything.
QGIS 3 - default marker symbology
QGIS Default Vector Layer Style
Is there any solution for this?
(I am running QGIS 3.34 on Linux KDE)

I'm not sure for existing projects, but for new ones you can create a new project, customize the default, then set this project to be the source for new projects (settings/options/general/project file/create new project from default project + set current project as default)


Thanks a lot for this, it is very useful ! To add some more information, this won't change anything when opening .shp layers directly from computer files. QGIS needs to be opened and a project created.

@rtu_11 For shapefiles (instead of projects), you can also create a QML style having the same name as the shapefile, it will automatically be loaded. See this post.
